# LINQ to SQL Joining Query returning 1 instead of 0

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, join, left-join

Whats the difference between these two query?

***I am getting 0 from codes1.Count() but 1 from codes2.Count() but it should be 0 for both.***

```
 IQueryable<SecurityCode> codes1 = (from user in dataBase.SecurityUsers
                         from code in user.SecurityCodes
                         where user.UsrUserName.Equals(code.UsrUserName)
                               && user.UsrPhone.Equals(phone)
                         select code);


 IQueryable<SecurityCode> codes2 = (from user in dataBase.SecurityUsers
                               where user.UsrPhone.Equals(phone)
                         select user.SecurityCodes.FirstOrDefault());
```

The relationship is displayed below

[image]

Any explanation will be highly appreciated.

Comment: FirstOrDefault returns default(TSource) if source is empty; otherwise, the first element in source (from MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx).

Comment: but why should i get 1 instead of 0?

Comment: also your first query is over complicated, there is no need for the where clause 'user.UsrUserName.Equals(code.UsrUserName)' as it is implied by 'from code in user.SecurityCodes' also == should be used instead of .Equals

Comment: The second query has a less strict `where` clause, yet you're surprised it returns more results. Apparently there is a record that matches the second query, but not the first.

Comment: @Prutswonder my whole table is empty..where should it come from?

Comment: See your accepted answer. If you add `&& user.SecurityCodes.Any()` to your where statement, you will get correct results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FirstOrDefault will always return exactly 1 element, regardless of if it exists. so your second query will always return elements. (one for each user)

Comment: i changed the second query to only First() instead of FirstorDefault() but still i am getting different result

Comment: First is no different only it will exception if there are no results. Like i said before you cant achieve what you want with the second query, you should simplify/modify the first to do what you want as its the correct one

Answer (score 0):

FirstOrDefault() on any collection means you will always get one result. That result will either be the first result encountered or a default value if not result was found.

If you change the second query to eliminate the FirstOrDefault(), the counts from both queries should produce the same result.

Comment: The second query is actually just straight up wrong, removing the FirstOrDefault will just cause it to not match the return type.

Comment: i changed the second query to only First() instead of FirstorDefault() but still i am getting different result