# Group and Count in Linq issue

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am working on a C# project using LINQToSQL,But right now I am having a problem with the following query:

```
var groupByQuery =  (from c in db.Customers
                            join o in db.Orders on c.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID into lf1
                            from or in lf1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            group c by c.CustomerID into g
                            select new
                            {
                                CustomerID = g.Key,
                                Count = g.Count()
                            }
                            ).OrderBy(x => x.Count);
```

As you can see I am doing a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and grouping by the `CustomerID`, and everything goes well so far. But when I see the results I realize that the `Customers` that does not have any `Order`, has a "1" in their `Count` field.

Why is that? The `Count` field is supposed to have a "0" in these cases, What am I doing wrong?

I found this questions here:

[linq-count-query-returns-a-1-instead-of-a-0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791614/linq-count-query-returns-a-1-instead-of-a-0)

[linq-to-sql-joining-query-returning-1-instead-of-0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652906/linq-to-sql-joining-query-returning-1-instead-of-0)

but none of them has been helpful to me, I hope someone can help, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There will still be a record, even if it's null - a set that contains "NULL" is still a row - that's why it's saying there is 1 record. If you give the `Count` method an argument for what  records to count, it should work better.

```
Count = g.Count(a => a.SomeNullableField != null)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But that's just my problem: from the `.Count()` method I cannot access any field from `Orders` table which stops me from knowing whether it has any Orders or not

Comment: Ah - group `or` by CustomerID instead of `lf1` to access the joined-in table.

Answer (score 1):

You're making things too complicated.  `join...into` performs a [group join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx), so the Orders are grouped by `CustomerId` within your first two lines of code.  This should work:

```
var groupByQuery =  (from c in db.Customers
                     join o in db.Orders on c.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID into lf1
                     select new
                     {
                         CustomerID = c.Id,
                         Count = lf1.Count()
                     }
                     ).OrderBy(x => x.Count);
```